# Why does Roblox pester me about being a robot?

Tags: roblox

It was my first time making a profile. I went and put in my username and password. Then I tapped I’m not a robot. It made me do the “test” and I passed, but every time I go to login, it I have to do the “test” to prove I’m not a robot. What exactly does this mean and why do I have to do it over and over again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone may try use a robot to log into your account and use your items. This is why Roblox has that as a feature.

Comment: Additionally, they use this feature to stop scammers from creating a mob of bots for popularity.

Comment: But, why do they have to do it when I try to login?

Comment: @DevilsbestfriendisLunar Probably so that they can prevent a bot from gaining site access *at all*, in case they forgot to anti-robot something destroyable there. Like a group. They can spam there.

Comment: Okay. Is it like a ‘in case some one tried being me’ type of a situation?

Comment: They check it every time  you log in so someone does not keep on spamming passwords with a bot until they find the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

To stop bots to login into your account. I am pretty sure it is possible if there was no verification, bots could try passwords for days and one time, get your password. You could lose all your robux, or your whole account.